# google analytic get user activity with multi user

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

```json
{
  "viewId": "199044260",
  "user": 
  {
    "type": "CLIENT_ID",
    "userId": "1624799839.1564022408"
  }
}
```

This json will send a request to get all session of user id (all activity).

How can send a request with more than one user id?

Answer (score 0):

You cant send more then one if you check the documentation it states that it must be a unique user id

[Method: userActivity.search](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search)

[image]